# Rest API - Get list items by column value

Tags: list, rest, column

Assuming there is a list of Students with their zip-codes in one of the columns, what is the query string needed to get only students with a certain zip-code?

So far here is what I've got:

`site.com/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Student')/?$what-goes-here=value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `$filter`

```
/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Student')/items?$filter='Internal Name of the column' eq "Some value"
```

Let me know the internal name of your column and value also so that I can write the exact query for you.

See more about `$filter` in my CodeProject Article.

**PS:** Ignore `''` from `'Internal Name of the column'`

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: If someone else reads this: this didn't work for me until I removed the single quotes from the column internal name

Comment: Good catch. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes without the `' '` from the 'Internal Name of the column' it worked for me. For the filter value I used in addition `' '`:

```
/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Student')/items?$filter=InternalNameOfTheColumn eq 'SomeValue'
```